# Given a 5% employee turnover per year: What is the average tenure time?

Tags: average

Is it possible, based on a given turnover rate per year (in %), to calculate the average time (in years) an employee stays in an organization?

I have looked at the Coupon Collector's problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem

but so far haven't been able to figure this out.

Turnover could basically be calculated like this:

[Turnover Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UFi1.png)

Comment: No coupons here....this is a straight forward example of a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: @lulu Only if we assume leaving is independent of length of service. But actually the average doesn't depend on who leaves when.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  Of course.  Obviously some model is needed here, but at the level of the OP (introductory, I assume) I think it is clear what assumptions are intended.

Comment: To clarify:  I believe the intended assumption is "each employee has a $5\%$ chance of leaving each year independent of their own history and independent of any other employee."

Comment: I think independence can be assumed in this problem. At least this was how I encountered the problem. No dependence on other variables was mentioned.

@lulu: Introductory hits the mark all to well

Comment: So, working with that assumption, can you solve the problem?  This really is just a geometric distribution...it's the same as saying "I have a coin that comes up $H$ with probability $.05$, what's the expected number of tosses before I see $H$".

Comment: @lulu No, my point was that *no* model is needed. If you maintain a constant turnover rate, that determines the average time.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime  Ah, fair point.  Of course, no matter what we do we need to take a limit in large time.  But, yes.  I agree that the large time limit should be model independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This strikes me as application of [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law)
$$L = \lambda W$$
where $L$ is the long-term average of the number of customers in a queuing system, $\lambda$ is the arrival rate, and $W$ is the average time a customer spends in the system.  Assuming the company size is stable, the turnover is the arrival rate of employees divided by the number of employees, i.e. turnover is
$$\tau = \lambda / L$$
so by Little's Law,
$$W = L / \lambda =1/ \tau$$
Put in words, the average time in the company is the reciprocal of the turnover rate.

I don't see any connection with the Coupon Collector's Problem.

Comment: I didn't know this had a name - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with the coupon collector problem.

Say the company has $100$ employees. After $1$ year they have employed $100$ people for a total of $100$ person-years. After $2$ years they have employed $105$ people for a total of $200$ person years. After $n$ years they have employed $100+5n$ people for a total of $100n$ person-years. So what is the average number of years worked, if $n$ is very large?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to apply basics of probability here, not sure whether I got everything right.

When

- The events are $\Omega = \{L_1, L_2, L_3, ..\}$, where $L_1$ is the employee leaving after the first year, $L_2$ is the employee leaving after the second year, and so on;
- $f = 0.05$ for a turnover rate of 5%.

Then the probability for leaving after the $i$th year is the probability for staying $i-1$ years and leaving in the $i$th year:

$P(X=L_i) = (1-f)^{i-1}*f$

The expected value is then 20 years for 5%, which would be inline with the answer for Little's law above.

Interestingly, when I draw a sample based on the probability distribution above, and make a boxplot, I get a median of ~13.